# Finding the limit of this arctan function; $\lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \arctan\left(\frac{T}{\omega}\right)$

Tags: limits, inverse-function

In doing some Laplace stuffs, I had to solve this limit somewhere in my calculation to proceed;

$$\lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \arctan\left(\frac{T}{\omega}\right)$$

where the original function was defined as $f(t) = \ln\left(1 + \frac{\omega^2}{s^2}\right)$.
Ordinarily, I know that the $\lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \arctan\left(T\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}$.
So I reasoned out that as $T \rightarrow \infty$, the expression $\frac{T}{\omega} \approx T$ and so the limit could be $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

1. Please verify this conclusion for me.
2. And indicate how this could be solved generally for inverse functions likes arctan.

Thanks.

Comment: Your second question is too vague. As for question1: your conclusion is true if you precise $+\infty$ (not just $\infty$) but not your "proof". $\frac{T}{\omega} \approx T$ has no precise meaning. You can replace it by: as $T\to+\infty,$ for $\omega>0$ fixed, $\frac T\omega\to+\infty.$

Comment: Cool @AnneBauval thanks. How would the proof be done? So I am not a Mathematician though, haha.

Comment: Simply combine what I wrote above with what you already knew ($\lim_{s\to+\infty}\arctan s=\frac\pi2$), applied to $s=\frac T\omega.$